# How to check element does exist after mustache templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I have this mustache setup:

```
$.getJSON('data/data.json', function(data) {
     var template = "<ul>{{#"+elements+"}}<li class=\"selector {{.}}\"></li>{{/"+elements+"}}</ul>";
     var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
     panel.html(html);
});
```

After this I need to add some action on my `<li>` element with class `selector`. But there is a little problem with this element rendering to DOM. So I use small function to check this element does exist, but something is wrong and I have no results...

```
$.fn.doesExist = function(){
    return $(this).length > 0;
};

var picker = $('li.selector');
if (picker.doesExist()) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log('log');
    })
}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li class="selector 01"></li>
    <li class="selector 02"></li>
    <li class="selector 03"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what it specifically the problem? does it return `undefined` , `null` or something? when you're firing `.doesExist()` ? console error?

Comment: Did you check that `$(this)` in `doesExist` method really points to `$('li.selector')` ?

Comment: note also that in jQuery plugin $(this) is equal to $($(this)) . You should use this instead of $(this)

Comment: There's something conceptually wrong with putting a click handler in place to test whether an element exists or not. If it doesn't exist, then there's nothing to click!

Comment: so i need to do this conversely?

Comment: Can you add to your question the html generated by Mustache ?

Comment: yeap, one second please

Comment: No, just `console.log('I exist')` without the click handler wrapper.

Comment: Make sure you bind the elements when the elements are loaded, completely. Share your complete code to verify.

Comment: @Lukas do you check the length after mustache is used?

Comment: yes, after mustache generates template

Comment: Is any asynchronicity involved?

Comment: this is only one action

Comment: You are performing the test inside the `$.getJSON()` callback aren't you?

Comment: OMG inside `$.getJSON` it works, much thx for this advice, but why exactly this happens, and it should not work independently of each other?

Comment: See explanation in answer below.

Comment: and again, much thx for help for everyone exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.getJSON('data/data.json', function(data) {
     var template = "<ul>{{#"+elements+"}}<li class=\"selector {{.}}\"></li>{{/"+elements+"}}</ul>";
     var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
     panel.html(html);
     //*******************
     // PERFORM TEST HERE
     //*******************
});

 //*******************
 // $.getJSON() is asynchronous so 
 // performing test here is too early.
 // The response from the server is guaranteed
 // not to have arrived yet.
 //*******************
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
if($('li.selector').length>0){
    $('li.selector').click(function(){
         alert("wow")
    })
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxdb9/2/)